# AJAX Show/hide content

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

before anyone complains ive tried google but there isnt a straight forward answer or tutorial of any sort..

Basically ive got articles where a paragraph is seen then a *read more" link which using some javascript it shows more content, although eventually this will slow down the website as the rest of the article is there but just hidden.

So my question is how would i set up a AJAX/PHP to bring in the content instead? i know how to set up a database on mysql and am i right in guessing i would need to type out the article in MySQL when storing it in there? sorry if everything im saying is confusing but im confused myself... if anyone could explain for an absolute beginner that would be great as google just isn't my friend even after hours of searching.

[image: readmore pic]

Think ive been misunderstood. The above screenshot ive already achieved but what im wanting to do now is instead of hiding content then displaying it on-click to have it being called in using AJAX, a database and php

Comment: How you decide that where will you insert read more? Maybe you can put content after read me in on div and then `toggle` that div

Comment: Sorry don't quite understand what you're trying to say.. The above screenshot is what ive already done what im trying to do now is that instead of the article being on the same HTML page but hidden to create a way for the rest of the article to be thrown in using AJAX, a database and php.

Comment: For starters you would probably have to have the full text saved in the database, and your shortened version as well.  If you just kept the whole thing in the database the only way I can think of to shorten it is echo substr($articletext, 0, 399) . "..."; that would have the server sent a 400 character long text with... at the end.  it still would require a full database pull though.

Comment: Not that it's really my business, but maybe the reason you can't find good data on this online is that you're making a negligible change.  It is simply text which isn't a lot of data, and I doubt it will make much of a difference in your load speed to AJAX it in rather than to hide it.  The SQL query will take the longest, and now you're adding another one, which equals another database query, and another server -> client connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a "PreviewCutoffIndex" or similar to the articles table.
2. On page load, display the article HTML / content up to the cutoff index.
3. For the "read more" button, put the article identifier into an attribute
4. Add a click handler that makes an Ajax call, to load the rest of the article

---

Markup would look something like this ("data-article-id" comes from PHP on the page load):

```
<div>
    <?php echo $mysqlResult["articleContent"]; ?>
</div>
<a id="moreButton" data-article-id="<?php echo $articleId; ?>" href='#'>Read More</div>
<div id="moreContent"></div>
```

Javascript (assume you're going to use JQuery):

```
$("#moreButton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var articleId = $(this).attr("data-article-id");

    // load article into "moreContent" div
    $("#moreContent").load("content.php?articleId=" + articleId);
});
```

Then the PHP `content.php` should return text (or more likely markup) for the remainder of the article, based on `$_GET("articleId")`.

Comment: I think i understand most of this but how would i write up the PHP file as this is the area im struggling with the most.. would i have 1 php file named 'content.php' then inside this file each article assigned a articleID (if so how do i do this) or is it simple a different php file per article?

Comment: @box 1 file named `content.php` -- use a query string parameter to specify the specific articleId, which you use to retrieve the article from the MySQL table.

Comment: @box I can't post mysqli query syntax as I'm not fluent with it -- but you know the idea, just `select article_content from articles where articleid = %articleId`, `$_GET("articleId")`

Comment: You're just writing a .php file that pulls the relevant text from the database and echoes it.  It is only one file that will handle every article.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough you specifically said you don't want to load the entire article, I'm still gonna say you should:

I'm quite sure your server load will be higher when using ajax to get the rest of each article, because you'll need another request per 'read more' action.

Plus if you're gzipping your request, a little more text won't matter a lot on the overal size of the request.

If you're running into a slow page load because of your articles, perhaps try looking into [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) (show like 20 articles in batches of 5, to make pages, rather than 20 articles all at once)

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with the ol' show/hide method in css?

see this for a pretty advanced method.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-showhide